How to import running helm release into ArgoCD
For our production clusters we want to adopt ArgoCD for the managemend of the cluster state.
We currently have many custome helm-charts deployed into this cluster, some of these are quite old. Let's suppose we don't have a the original helm-chart, but still want to on-board that release to be managed by ArgoCD.
Would be the correct apporche to use helm get hooks <release-name> -n <namespace> and helm get manifest <release-name> -n <namespace> to generate the yaml definition to be used by ArgoCD?
And what about would be do about the namespace that was created by helm by using the --create-namespace flag during installation?
So far I only found this, which does not go into detail on how to get the manifest data.
